# Animated pie chart with Plotly

Tags: python, animation, plotly, pie-chart

I have the following data stored in a pandas dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd
 
values = [[4500, 2500, 1053, 500],
          [872, 2389, 819, 765],
          [293, 1668, 873, 778],
          [1656, 861, 6137, 698]]

df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
print(df.to_markdown())
```

```
Output:
|    |    A |    B |    C |   D |
|---:|-----:|-----:|-----:|----:|
|  0 | 4500 | 2500 | 1053 | 500 |
|  1 |  872 | 2389 |  819 | 765 |
|  2 |  293 | 1668 |  873 | 778 |
|  3 | 1656 |  861 | 6137 | 698 |
```

I can plot a pie chart of a single row using plotly (either with px.pie or go.Pie). Here I plot the data from the last row.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=df.columns, values=df.iloc[-1])])
fig.show()
```

Is there a way to create an animated pie chart that would display the data from each row one after the other. It seems that plotly express supports animation for scatter and bar plots but I cannot find anything related to pie charts.
Note: I am only looking for help for doing this with plotly. I do know how to do this with matplotlib.

Comment: From what I've read on Plotly webpages is that animation via Plotly Express only supports line, scatter, and bar chats (and NOT pie charts). You can read more on Plotly animation [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/animations/) and on this [forum](https://community.plotly.com/t/plotly-animations/33852/4)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using the current version of plotly in R, I don't know about the python syntax but specifying the variable "frame" whilst defining the variables might work. In R, frame defines the dimension that varies with frame, and this feature might carry over. I've had success using this, and I got the original advice from https://plotly.com/r/animations/

How it might look

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=df.columns, values=df.iloc[-1])]
,frame= row
)
```

Hopefully there's enough crossover in how plotly works in both languages for this to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

## References

Take a look at the "Simple Play Button" and "Using a Slider and Buttons" sections from [Plotly documentation](https://plotly.com/python/animations/#current-animation-limitations-and-caveats)

## Code

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = 'browser'

values = [[4500, 2500, 1053, 500],
          [872, 2389, 819, 765],
          [293, 1668, 873, 778],
          [1656, 861, 6137, 698]]
headings =['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns = headings)

# create a dictionary
fig_dict = {
    "data": [],
    "layout": {},
    "frames": []
}

# create initial frame
initial_frame_values = df.iloc[0]

# add initial frame to dictionary
fig_dict["data"] = [go.Pie(labels=headings,
                           title="frame : 0",
                           values=initial_frame_values,
                           sort=False)]

# Loop through each row of df to create a list of frames 
# that will be displayed when Play button is pressed.
frames_list = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    current_frame_title = "frame : " + str(index+1)
    frames_list.append(
        go.Frame(data=[go.Pie(labels=headings,
                              values=row,
                              title=current_frame_title,
                              sort=False)])
    )

# create buttons for animations : Play, Pause
fig_dict["layout"]["updatemenus"] = [{
    "buttons": [{
            "args": [None, {
                "frame": {
                    "duration": 2000, # affects playback speed
                                "redraw": True
                },
                "fromcurrent": True,
                            "transition": {
                    "duration": 1000
                }
            }],
            "label": "Play",
                    "method": "animate"
        },
        {
            "args": [
                [None], {
                    "frame": {
                        "duration": 0,
                        "redraw": True
                    },
                    "mode": "immediate",
                    "transition": {
                        "duration": 0
                    }
                }
            ],
            "label": "Pause",
            "method": "animate"
        }
    ],
    "pad": {
        "r": 10,
        "t": 87
    },
    "showactive": False,
    "type": "buttons",
    "x": 0.1,
    "xanchor": "right",
    "y": 0,
    "yanchor": "top"
}]
# add our list of frames to our dictionary
fig_dict["frames"] = frames_list

# create final figure
fig = go.Figure(fig_dict)

# optional
fig_dict["layout"]["title"] = "my pie chart"
fig.update_layout(legend_title_text='stuffs')

fig.show()
```

## Result

### Before pressing Play button

[image]

### After pressing Play button

[image]

[image]

[image: frame 3]

[image]

## Note

- My images are cropped and exclude the Play and Pause buttons as well as the legend.
- Frames 0 and 1 are identical.
- Before pressing Play button, only frame 0 is displayed.
- After pressing Play button, frames 1-4 will be displayed and then animation stops.
- When Play button is pressed again, frames 1-4 will be displayed again and then animation stops. Notice that frame 0 is omitted afterwards.